# UIImage in an UIImageView rendering distorted

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an UIImageView 3 levels deep in a super view. (The white region on top of the gray rectangle is my superview, the gray elongated rectangle is one subview, the black square is another subview of the elongated gray rectangle, the cog is the image of the UIImageView which is a subview of the black square). The frame rectangle of the UIImageView is calculate as follows, where _normalImage is a UIImage object. I do this inside the subclass that represents the black square

```
    CGFloat xPoint = self.bounds.size.width/2 - _normalImage.size.width/2;
    CGFloat yPoint = self.bounds.size.height/2 - _normalImage.size.height/2;
    CGRect frameRect = CGRectMake(xPoint, yPoint, _normalImage.size.width, _normalImage.size.height);
    self.imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
```

[image]

The _normalImage is 26X26 and should be a perfect square. However the image is rendering as distorted as if there is an aspect ratio loss.

Whats wrong ?

Comment: Is `self` in this context the view with the black background, and do you ultimately add `imageHolder` as a subview of the black view?

Comment: Yes self is the black background. imageHolder is a subview of the black view

Comment: So when you `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.imageHolder.bounds))`, is the calculated frame the correct size?

Comment: If you have a retina display, try doubling the image resolution and add "@2x" suffix to its name.

Answer (score 0):

try using floorf() function for your coordinates to prevent them contain the fractional part.

Comment: They are all whole numbers no fractional part

Comment: Maybe it's an issue because of the Retina display?

Answer (score 0):

Image is stretched because by default it use UIViewContentModeScaleToFill content mode.

```
self.imageHolder.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: Nope, I tried drawing the image without the UIImageView (overrode drawRect of the UIView). The UIImageView should be a perfect square of 26X26. However I am getting a rectangle, (atleast visually it feels like it)